# valgrind giving fatal error at launching time

Tags: embedded-linux, valgrind

I have compiled valgrind for a embedded device, and executed the following command to check the leaks.

```
./valgrind --leak-check=full --xml=yes --xml-file=<xml file path> <application>
```

But it is giving the following error.

```
valgrind:  Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
valgrind:  which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
valgrind:  cannot be set up.  Details of the redirection are:
valgrind:
valgrind:  A must-be-redirected function
valgrind:  whose name matches the pattern:      strlen
valgrind:  in an object with soname matching:   ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
valgrind:  was not found whilst processing
valgrind:  symbols from the object with soname: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
valgrind:
valgrind:  Possible fixes: (1, short term): install glibc's debuginfo
valgrind:  package on this machine.  (2, longer term): ask the packagers
valgrind:  for your Linux distribution to please in future ship a non-
valgrind:  stripped ld.so (or whatever the dynamic linker .so is called)
valgrind:  that exports the above-named function using the standard
valgrind:  calling conventions for this platform.  The package you need
valgrind:  to install for fix (1) is called
valgrind:
valgrind:    On Debian, Ubuntu:                 libc6-dbg
valgrind:    On SuSE, openSuSE, Fedora, RHEL:   glibc-debuginfo
valgrind:
valgrind:  Note that if you are debugging a 32 bit process on a
valgrind:  64 bit system, you will need a corresponding 32 bit debuginfo
valgrind:  package (e.g. libc6-dbg:i386).
valgrind:
valgrind:  Cannot continue -- exiting now.  Sorry.
```

There is a library "ld-2.19.so" built along with valgrind, If I copy this library to /lib/ (replacing the existing ld-2.19.so under /lib/ with the same library built along with valgrind) then valgrind is running fine. Same tool chain was used to build rootfs for the embedded device and valgrind. Replacing existing "ld-2.19.so" with library built along with valgrind will not effect the report generating by valgrind?

Comment: What platform is this exactly? You should start with something simple (`--tool=none` and a small executable like `pwd` or `ls` or `/bin/echo`)

Comment: @PaulFloyd It's a Intel platform(atom processor). I have executed `./valgrind --tool=none ls`, but it is giving error `valgrind: failed to start tool 'none' for platform 'amd64-linux': No such file or directory`.

Comment: @PaulFloyd,  If we give tool as none then it is giving error as updated in the above comment.

Comment: Can you tell if you have a full installation of Valgrind? You should have [install dir]/libexec/valgrind/none-amd64-linux (for Linux on AMD64, it will be different for other OSes and hardware)

Comment: I have copied all valgrind files to one path and exported that path in VALGRIND_LIB, after that it is working fine.

Comment: Now I am using Valgrind to debug issues in the Arm platform. In the xml file, which Valgrind generated, it is showing "Leak_PossiblyLost" xml tags, but in the stack frame xml tags it is not showing any application functions where a leak is possible. It is showing Valgrind files only in the stack frame tags updated the tag snippet [here](https://pastebin.com/3yp8qpxE). Can you guide on this, how I can get the application source details where the leak possible. I have built the application binary, which is not stripped.

Comment: And you you see anything without `--xml=yes`?

Comment: I removed --xml=yes and  added --show-rechable=yes. I could see the library related entries like `==20471==    by 0x494ED1F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.14)` , but no details about the application call which landed in the library.

Comment: Can you help me to understand how Valgrind internally functions. How Valgrind will track the applications memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

"How Valgrind works" is a very long story. I'll try to keep it short.

- The launcher `valgrind` executable sets LD_PRELOAD to point to one or two Valgrind libraries then execs the tool executable (memcheck by default)
- The tool does not use libc. Instead it starts in assembler and has to setup its own stack and heap.
- It then loads the guest executable and ld.so into memory.
- If they have debuginfo it will read that, and also for itself. *****
- Then it starts to JIT interpret the guest machine code. This will go through the guest startup process, loading shared libraries and then executing 'main'.
- The startup will also load the LD_PRELOAD libs, which trigger some special actions related to redirection.

Since Valgrind is redirecting all of the malloc functions it can trace that memory.
memcheck maintains "shadow" memory which tells Valgrind whether the corresponding guest memory has been initialized or not. It also has a map of all allocated (and deallocated) memory, which it can use to tell whether memory is addressable or not.

Your problem seems to be where I put *****. Valgrind is failing to find any debuginfo for ld.so and so cannot redirect `strlen`.

I don't know what you are doing to build ld.so. It certainly isn't part of the standard Valgrind build, so I can't comment on that.

If your ld.so is correctly built then you should have no problems.